# How to prove that $H^1(0,1)/H^1_0(0,1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

- *Edit 2: As posteted I was missing crucial information.

  "Let $H^1(0,1)$ be mappings $f:(0,1) \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ "*
  The right result can be proved using $$T:H^1(0,1)/H^1_0(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2; \quad f \mapsto T(f):= \lim(f(x_n),f(y_n))$$

---

Prove that $H^1(0,1)/H^1_0(0,1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Here $H^1_0(0,1) := \overline{C^{\infty}_c(0,1)}$

I figured out a proof, but I'm quite uncertain if its right.

First define a mapping $T$. Let $x_n \rightarrow 1$ and $y_n \rightarrow 0$ then $$T:H^1(0,1)/H^1_0(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2; \quad f \mapsto T(f):= \lim(f(x_n),f(y_n),f'(x_n),f'(y_n))$$

- *Edit 1 : Here $f'(x)$ denotes the weak derivative.*

Now show : 1) $T$ is injective ;  2) $T$ is surjective ;  3) $T^{-1}$ is continuous

1)
 Let $$f,g \in H^1(0,1)/H^1_0(0,1) \text{ with  }  T(f)=T(g)$$ then:
 $$\lim f(x_n \to 1) = \lim g(x_n \to 1)   
 $$ $$\lim f(x_n \to 0) = \lim g(x_n \to 0)$$
 For  $h_0 := f-g $ we see that $h_0(x_n \to 1) = 0 = h_0(y_n \to 0)$ so  $h_0 \in H^1_0(0,1)$.
 Now $(g+h_0 = f) \Rightarrow (g \sim f)$ hence T is injective.

2) For $(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{C^2}$ define:
 $$f(x) := \begin{cases}
     cx+a   &\text{for } x\in  (0,\frac{1}{4})\\
     \frac{1}{4}c+a+(2x-\frac{1}{4})(-\frac{1}{4}d+b-\frac{1}      {4}c+a)&\text{for } x \in [\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}]\\
     dx+b-d &\text{for } x \in (\frac{3}{4},1)
   \end{cases} $$
Then for the weak derivative we get:
  $$f'(x) := \begin{cases}
     c   &\text{for } x\in  (0,\frac{1}{4})\\
     2(-\frac{1}{4}d+b-\frac{1}      {4}c+a)&\text{for } x \in [\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}]\\
     d &\text{for } x \in (\frac{3}{4},1)
   \end{cases} $$
Note: $f(y_n \to 0) = a, \quad f(x_n \to 1) = b, \quad f'(y_n \to 0) = c, \quad f'(x_n \to 1) = d $
From $ f \in L^2 $ and the existence of the weak derivative it follows that $f \in H^1(0,1)$
Concluding: $$\text{For every } z \in \mathbb{C}^2 \text{ we get a } f \in H^1(0,1)/H^1_0(0,1) \text{ with } T(f)=z$$
$T$ is surjective.

3) Take a look at the mapping defined in 2) and call it $T^{-1}$.
 $$T^{-1}: \mathbb{C}^2 \to H^1(0,1)/H^1_0(0,1) \quad (a,b,c,d) \mapsto f (x)$$
Now for $(a,b,c,d)_n \to (0,0,0,0)$ we get 
$$ \lim T^{-1}(a,b,c,d)_n = 0 \quad \text{for } x\in (0,1)$$ 
Hence $T^{-1}$ is continuous

As a bijective continuous mapping $T$ is an isomorphism and $H^1(0,1)/H^1_0(0,1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$.

---

Its a pretty unaesthetic proof and im not quite sure if it's right. 
Mostly I wonder about the correctness of 3).
I would really appreciate some improvements :D

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you see this result? Do you know it's true?

Comment: I came up with this by myself so I don't know if it's true.

Comment: Your operator $T$ is not well defined. For $f \in H^1(0,1)$, you do not have a value $f'(x_n)$, let alone the existence of the limit $\lim_{x_n \to 0} f'(x_n)$. Moreover, I would say that the result is true for complex-valued function spaces, but you worked with real-valued spaces. For real valued spaces, the quotient space should be isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I should clarify, with $f'(x)$ i mean the weak derivative, which is in $L^2(0,1) \text{ for } f \in H^1(0,1) := W^{1,2}(0,1)$. So it should exist in $(0,1)$ and so should the limit. Or am I missing out smth?

Comment: $f(x) = x^{3/4} \in H^{1}(0, 1)$ but the limit of $f'(x)$ as $x \to 0$ doesn't exist. The right result should really be $H^{1}(0, 1)/H^{1}_{0}(0, 1) \cong \mathbb{R}^{2}$, and the right map is just coming from boundary evaluation of functions in $H^{1}(0, 1)$, which are absolutely continuous.

Comment: I found out, that my exercise was missing information. The space $H^1(0,1)$ should actually be mappings $f:(0,1) \mapsto \mathbb{C}$. Then the result should stand, as mentioned by Eric, by boundary evaluation.